# placing static library answer in the beginning of flash section

Tags: ld, atmel, binutils, atmelstudio

I'm using atmelstudio to compile a firmware image and want to place the functions from static libraries (including the gnu's libc.a & libgcc.a) in the beginning of the .text section followed .text belong to my project source code. Right now what happen is the other way around.

This is my linker script

```
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sfixed = .;
    KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
    *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)    <-- my functions and functions from static libraries are within this rule
    *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)
    *(.rodata .rodata* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The star in `*(.text)`, means to match any object file. You need to give the name for the libc and put it first.  These are called *input sections* in the gnu ld manual.  The syntax according to the manual is `libc.a:(.text)`, you may order specific objects within a library, with `libc.a:strcmp.o(.text)`.

See: [Gnu Ld section 3.6.4.1 Input Section Basics](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Basics.html) for detailed information.

---

A solutions might be,

```
KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.)) 
.a:(.text .text. .rodata .rodata*) <-- this line 
*(.text .text. .gnu.linkonce.t.*) 
*(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7) 
*(.rodata .rodata .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
```

Comment: wonderful comment and link, from that site i learned how to control the placements of object in the output binary. In the end i added an entry which get me the effect i wanted
<code>
KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
*.a:(.text .text.* .rodata .rodata*)  <-- this line
*(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
*(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)
*(.rodata .rodata* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
</code>