# arm-none-eabi-gcc: SECTIONS: unclear syntax *<archivename>.a:

Tags: c, gcc, arm, linker-scripts

I could not find a clear answer to a very specific problem, even after reading several manual pages and guides. I work on a linker script for the tool chain mentioned in the title. During the development I was tying to link a static library (archived, .a) to a location in my RAM. I could **not** accomplish this task by handling it like a regular .o file as in the following example:

```
SECTIONS {
  outputa 0x10000 :
    {
    all.o
    foo.o (.input1)
    }
  outputb :
    {
    foo.o (.input2)
    foo1.o (.input1)
    }
  outputc :
    {
    *(.input1)
    *(.input2)
    }
}
```

After a long journey, I found a hint in another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300996/linker-script-input-sections-archive-aobject-o-syntax-issue). That lead me to my current solution:

```
...
    .ramlib : ALIGN(4)
        {
            *liblpcspifilib_M3.a: (*);
        } > RamLoc40  AT>MFlashA512
...
```

Please note the colon syntax. This will link all contents of `liblpcspifilib` as a block to the Ram. However without the ":" it won't link anything. Even after I found out how to solve the issue, I could not find any other information about that behaviour.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [placing static library answer in the beginning of flash section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497953/placing-static-library-answer-in-the-beginning-of-flash-section)

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the link to the similar question. I agree that both cases lead to the same solution, however my question is asked in a more generalized way. It is highly possible that one could have a similar issue not only when placing a library at the beginning of a flash section. The other question is about a specific task, my question is focusing on the syntax.

Comment: I'd like to clarify that I was thinking about the visibility ("searchability") of the answer when someone is looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this information is hard to find in the official GNU docs, so I assume it is some kind of extension. [Here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/resources/eecs373/Linker.pdf) on page 50 is telling us:

> You can also specify files within archives by writing a pattern
>   matching the archive, a colon, then the pattern matching the file,
>   with no whitespace around the colon.
>
> ```
> ‘archive:file’ matches file within archive
> ‘archive:’ matches the whole archive
> ‘:file’ matches file but not one in an archive
> ```

Comment: This is [another link to the same information](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Basics.html).  The form is `archive:file` and you can use wildcards on either side and then wildcards in the section.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying citation and link!